# Should users re-auth after migrating to new linkedin api?

Tags: linkedin-api

As Community Management API sunset soon and we must migrate to new API with new app, doesn't that mean current all users' access token will be not working? Because they contain clientID and new app means new clientID. Is that true?

Comment: I suggest to ask this a linkedin

Comment: I have sent them question via their zendesk just now

Answer (score 1):

Got a response from LinkedIn, users must reauthenticate because I requested with new app. Why I can't just use old app? My old app can't be used for requesting Community Management API.